# Dose unbalanced force applied on object not change both speed and direction together?

Tags: forces

"The change in the velocity could be due to change in its magnitude or the direction of or both." It is right I know.

But, "If an unbalanced force applied on the object,  there will be change either in its speed or in the direction of its motion " This two sentences is in book.

My question is "does unbalanced force applied on object will only change its speed or direction of motion??? Does it not change both speed and direction of motion together??

Comment: That depends on the force.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acceleration is the change (derivative) of velocity with respect to time, and both are vectors.  Acceleration equals force, a vector, divided by mass, a scalar.  So acceleration can occur due to: a change only in the magnitude of velocity (speed), a change only in the direction of velocity, or both a change in the magnitude and direction of velocity.

For an object acted on by a force vector in one Cartesian direction, call it the x direction, the magnitude of the velocity vector changes but the direction of velocity vector does not change (stays in the x direction).

For an object in uniform circular motion, the velocity is constant in magnitude but changes in direction as the object moves, and the force that provides this motion (e.g., gravity, or the tension in a string twirling the object) is a centripetal force.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is "does unbalanced force applied on object will only
> change its speed or direction of motion??? Does it not change both
> speed and direction of motion together??

It can change both its speed and direction, only change its speed, or only change its direction.

Take the example of circular motion. If the object is moving at constant speed, then only its direction is changing due to the centripetal force, which is the net force acting on the object towards the center of motion, causing centripetal acceleration.

On the other hand, if the circular motion is not at constant speed, but its motion is still circular, then the net force acting on it causes both a change in speed and change in direction. It involves both a centripetal force component (that changes its direction) and a tangential component, which causes a change in speed.

Finally if the motion is linear only, the net force causes only a change in speed.

Hope this helps.